# Setting recurring alarms

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have a reminder application which is supposed to notify the user on certain days at a specific time in the day every week when set.

The variable 'frequency_value' contains data for which days of the week the alarm should go off. It is a string of 1's and 2's where 2 signifies that the alarm should go off on that day of the week and is in the order of  Monday to Sunday.

So 1111112 means the alarm only goes off on Sundays and 1212111 means Tuesdays and Thursdays only.

But it isn't working properly. Can anyone help?

```
public void next_alarm(Context context)
{
    Integer day_sequence[] = new Integer[7];
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar alarm_time = Calendar.getInstance();
    String d[] = time.split(":");
    alarm_time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(d[0]));
    alarm_time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(d[1]));
    alarm_time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    switch(now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
    {
        case Calendar.SUNDAY:
            day_sequence = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
            break;
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
            day_sequence = new Integer[]{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1};
            break;
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:
            day_sequence = new Integer[]{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2};
            break;
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
            day_sequence = new Integer[]{4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3};
            break;
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:
            day_sequence = new Integer[]{5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4};
            break;
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:
            day_sequence = new Integer[]{6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
            break;
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:
            day_sequence = new Integer[]{7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
            break;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
        if(String.valueOf(frequency_value).charAt(day_sequence[i]) == '2')
        {
            Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(context, Task_Notification_BroadcastReceiver.class);
            myIntent1.putExtra("frequency_value", frequency_value);
            myIntent1.putExtra("task_time", time);
            myIntent1.putExtra("task_full_text", full_text);
            myIntent1.putExtra("task_text", text);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Integer.parseInt(time.replace(":", "0")), myIntent1,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarm_time.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, i+1);
            AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            assert alarmManager1 != null;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager1.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm_time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
                table_alarms_db.addAlarm(new Database_Alarms(null, alarm_time.getTimeInMillis(), time, text, full_text, frequency_value));
            }
            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                alarmManager1.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm_time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
                table_alarms_db.addAlarm(new Database_Alarms(null, alarm_time.getTimeInMillis(), time, text, full_text, frequency_value));
            }
            else {
                alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm_time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
                table_alarms_db.addAlarm(new Database_Alarms(null, alarm_time.getTimeInMillis(), time, text, full_text, frequency_value));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific on how is not working properly

Comment: @diedu the alarms don't go off when they are supposed to, I'm desperate so trying my luck here